# A possible GI isomorphic problem

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Here I try to seek if restricting the structure of permutations would still keep GI property.

Given a $2n$ vertex undirected graph whose vertices are partitioned arbitrarily in pairs to say WLOG $(1,2)$, $(3,4)$, $\dots$, $(2n-1,2n)$. Call these vertices pairs as super vertices.

Call two such graphs $2n$ vertex labelled graphs $G$, $H$ whose adjacencies are $A$ and $B$ respectively $\mathsf{vertex}$-$\mathsf{pair}$-$\mathsf{isomorphic}$ iff

**($\star$)** there is a permutation $P$ such that $A=PBP'$ on the condition that the permutation $P$ permutes only supervertices.

Note that only a subset $n!$ of permutations of $(2n)!$ allowed.

In particular,

**($\star$)** vertex $2i$ in $G$ is mapped to vertex $2j$ in $H$ by the permutation iff vertex $2i-1$ in $G$ must be mapped to $2j-1$ in $H$.

Is $\mathsf{vertex}$-$\mathsf{pair}$-$\mathsf{isomorphic}$ $\mathsf{GI}$-$\mathsf{complete}$?

Also posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53824/restricting-possible-permutations-in-graph-isomorphism-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is GI-complete.  Take two arbitrary connected graphs with degrees at least 2 (obviously a GI-complete class). For each vertex $v$, add a new vertex $v'$ and join it only to $v$.  The pairs $\{v,v'\}$ have the property you describe.

Comment: Are there $n$-vertex non-isomorphic graphs with adjacency matrix $A$ and $B$ such that for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we can find a bijection between entries of $A^i$ and entries of $B^i$ as (multi)sets?

Comment: @Arul: I'm not sure I understand the question, but two non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs with the same parameters probably answers it.

Comment: I meant whether there is an example where we can find a bijective map $g_i:A^i→B^i$ considering $A^i$ and $B^i$ as multisets of $n^2$ values at every $i∈{1,…,n}$ when $A$ and $B$ are non-isomorphic?

Comment: @Arul: So you just want the number of entries of each value to be the same in  $A^i$ and $B^i$.  Strongly-regular graphs will do that.  For each $i$, the $(j,k)$ entry in $A^i$ depends only on whether $j$ and $k$ are equal, adjacent, or not-adjacent.  Those three values depend only on the strong-regularity parameters $n,k,\lambda,\mu$, not on the graph structure.

Comment: sorry to ask again. WHat are the known techniques used to attack GI. Is it only group theory and linear programming? Are there other techniques?

Comment: @Arul: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1493 for the most successful practical methods.